# Magento 1 order invoice does not support Arabic font

Tags: magento-1.9, pdf

I am printing invoice pdf of Magento 1.9.2 in Arabic, but its showing box only.

Note: Its not supporting only on PDF invoice printing, but Arabic supporting everywhere else.

You can see invoice PDF copy screenshot

[image]

Comment: @mbalparda Arabic supporting in other place only not supporting when generating invoice for printing

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that the bundled fonts `/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Re-4.4.1.ttf`, `/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_Bd-2.8.1.ttf` & `/lib/LinLibertineFont/LinLibertine_It-2.8.2.ttf` don't support the required font characters to show Arabic.

These are currently referenced in `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Abstract.php`

You could try implementing `_setFontRegular`, `_setFontBold` & `_setFontItalic` and using your own safe font?

Comment: I have resolved that issue but there is no option to add my answer